restoring windows automatic file backup to different computer
I have (actually Had) a Windows 10 PC which was setup to auto backup specific folders.  The backups are written to an external drive.  That PC died, and I want to Restore those folders/files to a New PC.   I can access the backed-up files on the external drive (with just File Explorer) but even though I can copy the folder structure over to the new PC, the actual files names have been modified to reflect the date/time of the backups.  For example, in a web project folder, there is a file "about (2023_10_06_20_48_34 UTC).aspx".  It would appear that I could manually go thru all the folders/files of interest, select the appropriately dated files and rename them; but that seems ominously burdensome :)   I just don't see a way to use the actual "backup/restore" mechanism to get this done.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

There are various tools that can rename a large set of files. As you have posted on Stackoverflow I assume you are familiar with development, therefore Python or other batch/scripting languages could be used. Alternatively there are a lot of rename tools available for Windows starting with old but good open source tools like "Ant Renamer" to to modern tools like PowerRename from Microsoft Power toys.
